# Can't use TearFree Option for Intel and DRI_PRIME at the same time (Hybrid Graphics)

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, amd-graphics, 19.04

So i have a Thinkpad with the RX550 and the Intel integrated graphics card. To eliminate tearing i found this fix (added to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`):

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

But after adding this i can't switch to the the `dGPU` using `DRI_PRIME=1` anymore, it just uses the Intel GPU.

Ist there any way to have both? I'm using the 19.04 Beta.

Comment: I don't have an RX550 but on my rig I add a second entry for nVidia GTX 970M and have no problem using `prime-select intel` or `prime-select nvidia` depending on my needs.

Comment: Well prime-select is for nvidia only. But I'll try to make an entry for each graphics card.